# Proof that the predual of the space of bounded operators is the space of trace class operators

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, dual-spaces

The Wikipedia article on [predual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predual) states without proof:

> For example, the predual of the space of bounded operators is the space of trace class operators.

How to prove this? Alternatively, could you suggest me a reference (with the exact section or page number) where I can look this up?

**P.S**: I haven't taken a formal class in functional analysis but I need to understand this in order to understand a certain concept in quantum information theory. So something at the beginners level would be helpful.

Comment: I tried to find a simple explanation but all I found was a general result on von Neumann algebras (Takesaki, Theory of Operator Algebras I, chapter 5, theorem 2.18).

Answer (score 1):

Let $B (H) $ be the algebra of bounded linear operators on $H $ and $L^1 (H) $ the trace-class operators. Define $\gamma:B (H)\to L^1 (H)^*$ by $$\gamma (T)(S)=\operatorname {Tr}(TS). $$ It is not hard to check that  $\gamma $ is linear and isometric, so it gives an embedding of $B (H) $ into the dual of  $L^1 (H) $. And, with some work, one can check that $\gamma $ is also surjective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you suggest a reference where I can look this up in more detail?

Comment: Not right now (mobile) but I'll give you something in a few hours.